# TracError: Unsupported version control system "svn": cannot import name fs

Tags: centos, svn, python, trac

I started out with a duplicate database entry error, and in trying to fix it am no longer able to resync my Trac database at all. Unable to import all the history I tried to upgrade from 0.12 to 1.0.1, however now when i run the sync either nothing happens or I get the error `TracError: Unsupported version control system "svn": cannot import name fs`.

Try to resync all repositories does nothing

```
[/var/trac/repo]# trac-admin . repository resync "*"
Done.
```

Specifying a repo returns an error

```
[/var/trac/repo]# trac-admin . repository resync "MyRepo"
TracError: Unsupported version control system "svn": cannot import name fs
```

The error originally said "svn" but running `pip install svn` got me where I am now, but `pip install fs` won't get me past this error.

Tried:

- changing to an older Trac with `easy_install Trac==0.12` and back with `easy_install Trac==1.0.1`
- install dependencies with pip: `pip install svn`, `pip install fs`
- tried running both "resync" and "sync" commands.

System:

- CentOS 5.10
- python 2.7.5
- Trac 1.0.1

Comment: Do you have access to the trac-admin source to see where in the code the svn message is coming from?
Is the "repository" you're referencing in your command line call an SVN repository or something else? It's suspicious that you had to install svn for python if Trac had an underlying svn repo in your 0.12 working version. What version of svn are you running?

Comment: @kiminoa I just got this working, but to answer a few of your questions: the error was coming from python not finding the SVN swig bindings. This was mainly due to 0.12 using python2.4 and 1.0 using python2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get this working by completely removing Trac 0.12 from both the system default python 2.4 site-packages as well as my python2.7. I used `pip` to remove `Trac` and `svn` and `yum` to remove `subversion`. At this point I had to build `pcre`, `swig`, `subversion`, and `svn-python` from source to get it to work.

Source files:

- [PCRE](ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/)
- [SWIG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swig/files/swig/)
- [Subversion](http://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/)

This assumes that python2.7 is install under `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` with libraries under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Install PCRE:

```
wget ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre-8.36.tar.gz
tar -xzvf pcre-8.36.tar.gz
cd pcre-8.36
./configure
make && make install
```

Install SWIG (specify `--with-python=/path/to/python2.x`):

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/swig/swig-3.0.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf swig-3.0.2.tar.gz
cd swig-3.0.2
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
make && make install
```

Install Subversion (specify `PYTHON=/path/to/python2.x`)

```
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/subversion-1.7.9.tar.gz
tar -xzvf subversion-1.7.9.tar.gz
cd subversion-1.7.9
./configure PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
make && make install

make swig-py
make check-swig-py
make install-swig-py
echo /usr/local/lib/svn-python \
           > /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subversion.pth
ldconfig
```

Install Trac

```
pip2.7 install trac
```

Once completed I was able to successfully resync my repository. Don't forget to enable `svn` in your Trac config, it is no longer on by default in 1.0+.

```
[root@dev1 ~]# trac-admin /var/trac/myrepo repository resync "MyRepo"
Resyncing repository history for MyRepo... 
5827 revisions cached.
Done.
```

Comment: I was able to do most of this by following this document: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/swig/INSTALL